# ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence - trying to get most common day from a dataframe

Tags: python, valueerror

I get this error when I try to get the most common day repeated in the dataframes i have

> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

here's the column i added to the dataframe

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday
```

here's the code that has the error

```
com_day_num = df['day_of_week'].value_counts().idxmax()
com_day_text = 'N/A'

if com_day_num == 0:
    com_day_text = 'monday'

if com_day_num == 1:
    com_day_text = 'tuesday'

if com_day_num == 2:
    com_day_text = 'wednesday'

if com_day_num == 3:
    com_day_text = 'thursday'

if com_day_num == 4:
    com_day_text = 'friday'

if com_day_num == 5:
    com_day_text = 'saturday'

if com_day_num == 6:
    com_day_text = 'sunday'


most_com_day= com_day_text
print("Most Common Day of Week: ", most_com_day)
```

Comment: df reproduction please, if we wish to help you debug it

Comment: i have no clue what that means

Comment: May we see an example of a dataframe please? Right now we can't reproduce it :-)

Comment: its a csv file with the date in dd/mm/yy and i took out the weekday from the date in python

Answer (score 0):

Note idxmax only returns the first occurence of max value in a column. You may have more than one occurence and so above code will not return all values.

```
dates['day_of_week'] = dates['DateTime'].dt.weekday

newdf=pd.DataFrame(dates['day_of_week'].value_counts())

list(newdf.iloc[np.where(dates['day_of_week'].value_counts()== dates['day_of_week'].value_counts()).max())].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import calendar
import datetime
def find_max_weekdays(df):
    dates=pd.DataFrame(df.index)
    dates['day_of_week'] = dates['DateTime'].dt.weekday
    newdf=pd.DataFrame(dates['day_of_week'].value_counts())
    d=dict(zip(calendar.day_name,range(7)))
    max_day=list(newdf.iloc[np.where(dates['day_of_week'].value_counts()==(dates['day_of_week'].value_counts()).max())].index)
    res = dict((v,k) for k,v in d.items())
    for i in max_day:
        print(res[i])

find_max_weekdays(df)
```